# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined javascript .filter()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this React method that handles when the user select something from a dropdown list

```
handleAreeTematicheChange(values) {
        if (Object.keys(values).length >= 0) {
            let newValue = [];
            const newAreeTematiche = values;
            if (Object.keys(values).length > 1) {
                newValue.push({ value: '-1', label: `${Object.keys(values).length} aree tematiche selezionate` });
            } else {
                newValue = values;
            }
            const newList = [];
            for (const filter in newAreeTematiche) {
                newList.push(newAreeTematiche[filter].value);
            }
            const filterAreeTematiche = values.filter(item => item.value !== '-1' && newList.indexOf(item) === -1);
            const newListString = newList.join('|');
            this.setState({ filterAreeTematiche, selectedAreeTematiche: newListString });

            this.onReloadAllElements(newListString);
        } else {
            this.setState({ filterAreeTematiche: [], selectedAreeTematiche: undefined });
            this.onReloadAllElements(null);
        }
    }
```

The error is triggered by

`const filterAreeTematiche = values.filter(item => item.value !== '-1' && newList.indexOf(item) === -1);`

I'm pretty sure that the problem is that `values` is an object in that moment so `.filter()` doesn't work because it works only on arrays.

It also gave me errors errors with `.length` and i resolved it with `Object.keys`, as you can see.
How can I filter an object? Do I have to convert it to array?

Comment: Problem (_"I'm pretty sure that the problem is that values is an object...works only on arrays"_) and answer (_"...and i resolved it with Object.keys"_ which returns an array) are already in the question. So what's the problem?

Comment: I don't know if i can use Object.keys also to filter an object

Comment: `newList.indexOf(item) === -1` will not work because `.indexOf()` does not know how to compare objects like you would need it in this case.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] with example input and the expected output.

Comment: I tried with object.keys on both and it worked, thank you. Can you add the answer? i can't beacuse of reputation

Comment: As mentioned. Please add a [mcve]. Right now, at least to me, the content of `handleAreeTematicheChange` looks strange and there's room for an optimized version. But that depends on the actual content of `values`.

Comment: i'll do it. It's strange because it's old code, so an optimized version could be way better

Comment: Apparently i can't find a sandbox that supports my code in ES6, your help was useful anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, Object.filter is invalid, so convert the object into an array of keys and use those keys inside the function to get the values as follows. Just replace the "*filterAreeTematiche*" value with the following.

```
const filterAreeTematiche = Object.keys(values)
                                  .filter(k => (values[k] !== '-1' && newList.indexOf(values[k]) === -1))
                                  .map(key => ({ value: values[key] }));
```

This will return you an array of objects with a single key "value". Since I don't know what exactly you want in the state, I just showed an example with "value" key, you can change the object as how you want in the map function.